# How to continue coding one line deeper in PineScript without violating the syntax?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

How to continue coding one line deeper in PineScript without violating the syntax?

I am writing a quite complex program where I need to calculate many values. I want to avoid that I do a very long calculation only in one line, because then you have to go back and forth to the side all the time and have no overview.

So how can I spread a calculation over several lines without violating the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your next line should start with one or several spaces (different from multiples of 4). You can read more information from [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Line_wrapping.html).

```
a = open + high + low + close

a = open +
      high +
          low +
             close
```